# drupal7 blocked user show content not anonymous

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Does anyone know if it is possible in Drupal 7 to show a piece of content (a Page) to a blocked user that an anonymous user can not access?

If so how to you go about doing it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new content type (or a node) for blocked users.

Then you will need to code a custom module for that. Inside this module you'll need to implement [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), and the code would be similar to this

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_node_access($node, $op, $account)
{
    if($op == "view" && $node->type == "YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE" && $account->status != 0)
    {
        return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
}
```

You can then use these nodes inside a block/view or any way you like.

Kindly note that I haven't tested the code, tell me if you have any problems getting it to work.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.